# How to fetch by id from Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying so hard for a couple of hours but it seems so difficult for such a simple thing. i need to fetch by id from Firebase and here is the code that I am using but which is not working:

```
fetch_selected_restaurant = () => {  
    var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants').where("res_id", "==", "5").get();  
}
```

Comment: The syntax you're using is for querying Cloud Firestore, but you tagged with Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and don't share APIs. Which database are you looking to use?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ah sorry, I am using Cloud Firestore actually

Comment: OK. I updated your question and tags. You can do that yourself too, by clicking the little `edit` link that shows under your question. Next up: what about the code that you shared doesn't work? Note that's it's typically best to include some `console.log(...)` statements in your code. That way you can show what they print, and what you expected them to print.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the problem is that it is not printing anything at all. Do you a solution to that?

Comment: If the code you shared is all you have, you're not processing the query snapshot that you get from `get()`. I highly recommend checking out the documentation on getting documents from a collection here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that reading firestore/firebase database is an **asynchronous** operation.

If you want to read document by **id**, you have to call it like that:

```
 var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants').doc(yourDocId).get()
```

If you remember, few lines above I mentioned that almost all operations with firestore are **asynchronous**, reading document is not an exception. After you call `get()` it returns `Promise`. I see you stored this promise in `ref` variable, that`s fine.

Now in order to get a result, you have to ask this promise for results. On this step you can get what you want:

```
ref.then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```